# MySQL - select - max - group by - efficiency

Tags: mysql, select, join, max

I have a question regarding performance of the MySQL DBMS.
Perhaps a trivial matter.
There are two tables and I need to get result as below :

```
     PLAYERS                           VISITS
     ID | PLAYER_NAME                  ID | PLAYER_ID | SEEN
     ----------------                  ---------------------------
     1  | user 1                        1 | 2         | 2012-12-12
     2  | user 2                        2 | 2         | 2012-12-13
     3  | user 3                        3 | 3         | 2012-12-13
     4  | user 4                        4 | 3         | 2012-12-14
                                        5 | 3         | 2012-12-14
                                        6 | 2         | 2012-12-15
RESULT:
ID | PLAYER_NAME | LAST_SEEN  
----------------------------
 1 | user 1      | NULL / 'NEVER'
 2 | user 2      | 2012-12-15
 3 | user 3      | 2012-12-14
 4 | user 4      | NULL / 'NEVER'
```

My current query is :

```
   SELECT 
   players.id, 
   players.player_name, 
   MAX(visits.seen) AS last_seen
   FROM players
   LEFT JOIN visits ON players.id = visits.player_id
   GROUP BY players.id,players.player_name
```

Works for me but it seems to me that it should be a more efficient method.

It's just key part of a larger query.

Thomas

Comment: Why group by player_name? Why `LEFT JOIN` and not `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: he has an aggregate function 4035

Comment: do you want the nulls or not

Comment: Why would you think that the query with the left join and aggregation is inefficient?

Comment: @DrewPierce - I need nulls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this join efficient there has to be an index on `player_id` in `VISITS`. Look into

```
`CREATE INDEX`
```

here.

To check the query efficiency you can always use:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT /* your select here */
```

Also if `PLAYERS.ID` is unique and primary key it's perfectly fine to group only by this id.

```
SELECT 
   players.id, 
   players.player_name, 
   MAX(visits.seen) AS last_seen
FROM players
   LEFT JOIN visits ON players.id = visits.player_id
GROUP BY players.id
```

but your original query is perfectly fine. Make sure you fully understand `GROUP BY` and the consequences for columns not included in `GROUP BY` if you omit columns. This can have unintended consequences in other queries (where the same id doesn't mean the same name i.e.)

Comment: It's perfectly fine only with settings that allow it. It's not the best practice (even if it slightly more efficient.)

Comment: Could you explain? I don't quite get it.

Comment: The query will be rejected with error if the [`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) mode has been enabled.

Comment: And about the best practice comment, I mean that it's not something that novices in SQL should use, as it can lead to indeterminate results (in other situations, not here. You correctly state that it will work fine if the `players(id)` is either unique or the primary key.)